# Gtk GUI - Select next control

Tags: gtk

When Gtk GUI is started seems that Gtk sets "optimal" focus order to his controls which can be switched (beside usual way) with arrows. Then we can easily move (modify) focus order with "grab" to whatever enabled widget.
In case of GtkEntry, after pressing enter key "activated" event raises where I do validation and then I would like to jump to next control, like I was pressed "down arrow".
For now I transfer focus with "grab" and explicit name of wanted control but I would like to jump to "next" control of gtk's order without referencing it.
Also I transfer focus manually in keypress event of entry but this is also too fixed and unwanted way.
If I woud be able to set focus to "next control" this can make later modification in GUI much simpler.

Is this possible and how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyGTK FAQ has one way to [set tab order](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.035.htp) and [two](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq05.020.htp) different [ways](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq14.028.htp) to traverse it. These are likely the same in whatever language you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I'm searching for. I use C language and my working solution is gtk_widget_child_focus(GTK_WIDGET(table1), GTK_DIR_DOWN);

Comment: Tobias, I try to vote up your answer but software don't allow me. Sorry.